# Where is dualboot.sh?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android

I want to install Ubuntu touch, dualbooted with android, as explained in this section:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation

There seems to be one problem though, the link to the dualboot.sh script is broke:
http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/latest/dualboot.sh

I searched all trough google, but I can't mamage to find a download link for this script.

Can somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I've read the wiki page. I know the consequences and I want to develop for Ubuntu touch. I have a N4, so I thought: "why not!" :D

Comment: OK, just hadda touch 1st base, because not everyone here with an eight score has your skill set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/20131220/dualboot.sh

Someone should update that wiki page.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look in  http://humpolec.ubuntu.com/latest/UPDATE-UbuntuInstaller.zip in META-INF/com/google/android/updater-binary